# Add new column to dataframe using Pandas but it goes beyond the length of the data

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

Im trying to add a new column to a pandas dataframe. Also, I try to give a name to index to be printed out in Excel when I export the data

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

#read csv file
file='RALS-04.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(file)

#select the columns that I want
column1=df.iloc[:,0]
column2=df.iloc[:,2]
column3=df.iloc[:,3]

column1.index.name="items"
column2.index.name="march2012"
column3.index.name="march2011"
df=pd.concat([column1, column2, column3], axis=1)

#create a new column with 'RALS' as a defaut value
df['comps']='RALS'

#writing them back to a new CSV file
with open('test.csv','a') as f:
    df.to_csv(f, index=False, header=True)
```

The output is the 'RALS' that I added to the dataframe goes to Row 2000 while the data stops at row 15. How to constrain the RALS so that it doesnt go beyond the length of the data being exported? I would also prefer a more elegant, automated way rather than specifying at which row should the default value stops at.

The second question is, the labels that I have assigned to the columns using columns.index.name, does not appear in the output. Instead it is replaced by a 0 and a 1. Please advise solutions.

Thanks so much for inputs

Comment: When using `pd.read_csv`, you can use `usecols=` to select the columns you want, and `names=` to define the column names on import. You can also use `df.to_excel` to write directly to an excel file.

Comment: In addition to @Stev s comment: pandas csv reader functionality is [well documented on their website](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html)

Comment: can you select multiple columns using usecols= ? and they're not next to each other. so for example how do you extract just column 0, 2 and 3?

Comment: I'm sure you've figured it out by now but `usecols=[0, 2, 3]` should work.

Comment: yes, just simply rename it with df.columns=['col1', 'col2'] and so forth... Thx